File upload state update
I'm writing a web form for uploading an audio file. When no file is uploaded, the data_list.value name is set to 'No file'. However, when a file is uploaded, the file name should be assigned to State.name_file, and the State.name_status should change from False to True. This way, the Send button should appear.
State
    class State(rx.State):
        name_file: str = 'No file'
        progress: int = 0
        total_bytes: int = 0
        name_status: bool = False

    rx.data_list.item(
        rx.data_list.label('File'),
        rx.data_list.value(
            rx.cond(
                rx.selected_files('upload1')[0],
                rx.badge(
                    rx.selected_files('upload1')[0],
                    variant='soft',
                    radius='medium',
                ),
                rx.badge(
                    State.name_file,
                    variant='soft',
                    radius='medium'
                ),
            ),
        ),
        align='center'
    ),

    rx.cond(
        State.name_status,
        rx.button(
            'Send',
            size='2',
            variant='surface',
            color_scheme='gold',
            radius='large',
            on_click=lambda: State.handle_upload(
                rx.upload_files(
                    upload_id="upload1",
                    on_upload_progress=State.handle_upload_progress,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    rx.button(
        'Clear',
        size='2',
        variant='surface',
        color_scheme='red',
        radius='large',
        on_click=lambda: State.clear_default_name('upload1')
    ),

I'm not very familiar with Reflex, and I also can't find good tutorials on it since there aren't any available. However, I still need to create this kind of page.
